# Xamarin MediaElement Zoom, Pan, AnchorX, AnchorY

Tags: xamarin, video, zooming, anchor, pan

I have a Xamarin MediaElement:

`<xct:MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" Source="video.mp4" AutoPlay="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" ShowsPlaybackControls="False" PropertyChanged="mediaElement_PropertyChanged" MediaOpened="mediaElement_MediaOpened"></xct:MediaElement>`

Which I can zoom and pan up/down/left/right.

After zooming then panning, the anchor for the next zoom stays at (.5, .5); the middle of the video.

I need it to zoom in on the center of the video based on where the video is on the screen after the zoom/pan is performed.

For example:

My screen is 788x397 (landscape).
The video fits the screen: AspectFill
The video is then zoomed (`mediaElement.Scale`) to 2.
The video is then panned to the right (`mediaElement.TranslationX`) 100px.
At this point, when zooming, I need it to zoom in/out at the panned/scaled location, which is no longer (.5, .5).

1. I tried to calculate the new center point based on the translation; ex. `mediaElement.AnchorX` = .6, `mediaElement.AnchorY` = .5, but the zoom did some wierd things as the calculation of AnchorX/AnchorY was updated while zooming.
2. I tried not changing the AnchorX/AnchorY at all, and forcing (.5, .5), but both these solutions zoomed based on the center of the video, and not the center of the video in relation to where it is on the screen.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the C# and XAML code for each Xamarin.Slider:

```
// zoom

private void sliderZoom_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    double zoom = ((sender as Slider).Value / 10) + 1;
    mediaElement.Scale = zoom;
}

<Slider x:Name="sliderZoom" 
        Maximum="100" 
        Minimum="0" 
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        WidthRequest="150" 
        HeightRequest="30" 
        BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
        ValueChanged="sliderZoom_ValueChanged" />
```

```
// pan horizontal

private void sliderPanHorizontal_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double pan = (((mediaElement.Scale * Content.Width) - Content.Width)/2) * ((sender as Slider).Value / 100);
    mediaElement.TranslationX = pan;
}

<Slider x:Name="sliderPanHorizontal" 
    Maximum="100" Minimum="-100" Value="0"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
    WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="30" 
    Rotation="180"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent" ValueChanged="sliderPanHorizontal_ValueChanged" />
```

```
// pan vertical

private void sliderPanVertical_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double pan = (((mediaElement.Scale * Content.Height) - Content.Height) / 2) * ((sender as Slider).Value / 100);
    mediaElement.TranslationY = pan;
}
<Slider x:Name="sliderPanVertical" 
    Maximum="100" Minimum="-100" Value="0"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
    WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="30" 
    BackgroundColor="Transparent" ValueChanged="sliderPanVertical_ValueChanged" />
```

Comment: how can we suggest fixes to code we can't see?

Comment: @Jason I added the code to the question.

Comment: If you set the `AnchorX` and `AnchorY ` after it translate,could it work ?